# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKOverlayAppConfiguration

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, cocoapods, google-ads-api

**"*OBJC_CLASS*$_SKOverlay", referenced from:       objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADInAppStoreMonitor.o)   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_SKOverlayAppConfiguration", referenced from:       objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(GADInAppStoreMonitor.o)**

that's suddenly occured to me after i add Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK to my project and i tried to add many of frameworks but it didn't worked [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyHHe.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Decrement the Pods version of Google Mobile ads sdk to  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK','~> 7.69' in the pods file and do pod install